# What does ついてる mean in 何かついてるじゃないの?

Tags: translation, meaning

Context:

> 加代ちゃんの誕生日が悟と同じ日だった。
>   何かついてるじゃないの。

Can't get meaning of the second phrase. What does つく (ついてる) mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> つく

「つく」 means:
６ 偶然などがうまく味方して、都合よく事が運ぶ。運が向く。
Chance takes sides well, and things go conveniently. lucky

A sample sentence:「今日はついている I am lucky today. 」

https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/147036/meaning/m0u/

Comment: あのう、日本語でそんなに上手じゃないんですけど。。。ちょっとわかりにくいんです。英語で教えてくれませんか？

Comment: それは、文の意味は「なんかはLuckyじゃないですか」のか？

Comment: @botichelli A free translation would be "That's (making me feel) kinda lucky, isn't it?"